# RegEx results in infinite loop/error - Requested entity too large

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, regex

The following code should check if either a `#` or `@` symbol has been found in a string. The regex should find each and every `@` or `#` and either place each instance it found into the `messages` table (if it was an `@` symbol), or if it was a `#` symbol it should insert the instance into the `hashtags` table or update an existing record if the hashtag is already in the table.

Currently, the script itself works fine, but when using the code with javascript through AJAX, the console responds by saying the requested entity (this script) is too large (or something of that caliber). I'd assume its getting stuck in an endless loop, but so far I haven't found a (working) better way to do this. So, what would be a better way of coding this?

```
if (preg_match_all("/[@]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/i", $post, $matches)) {
        for ($i = 0;$i <= $matches;$i++) {
            $match = str_replace("@", "", $matches[$i]);
            foreach($match as $key=>$mVal) {
                $uMSQL = "INSERT INTO `messages` (`to`, `from`, `message`, `sent`) VALUES (:to, :from, '<p>tagged you in a post</p>', NOW())";
                $uMQ = $con->prepare($uMSQL);
                $uMQ->bindParam(':from', $author, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $uMQ->bindParam(':to', $mVal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $uMQ->execute();
            }
        }
    }
    if (preg_match_all("/[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/i", $post, $hashtags)) {
        for ($h = 0; $h <= $hashtags; $h++) {
            $htMatched = $hashtags[$h];
            foreach($htMatched as $key=>$htVal) {
                $htCheck = "SELECT COUNT(hashtag) FROM `hashtags` WHERE `hashtag` = '$htVal'";
                $htQ = $con->query($htCheck);
                $htExistence = $htQ->fetchColumn();
                if ($htExistence >= 1) {
                    $addTU = "UPDATE `hashtags` SET `used` = used+1 WHERE `hashtag` = '$htVal'";
                    $updateHT = $con->exec($addTU);
                } else {
                    $htMSQL = "INSERT INTO `hashtags` (`hashtag`) VALUES (:hashtag)";
                    $htMQ = $con->prepare($htMSQL);
                    $htMQ->bindParam(':hashtag', $htVal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $htMQ->execute();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

AJAX

```
 function sendData() {
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://localhost/NextIt/ajax/sendPost.php";
    var txtField = window.frames['richTextField'].document.body.innerHTML;
    var access = document.getElementById('postTo').selectedIndex;
    var acc = document.getElementById('postTo').options;
    var accss = acc[access].text;
    var vars = "post="+txtField+"&access="+accss;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (hr.readyState === 4 && hr.status === 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        $('status').innerHTML = return_data;
        window.frames['richTextField'].document.body.innerHTML = '';
    }
}
    hr.send(vars);
    $('status').innerHTML = "Posting...";
}
```

The post_max_size in php_ini is 8M.  It is sending the data to a PHP script(above) through AJAX Post. The only "error" I'm getting is in the console (e.g. "Requested entity too large") Other than that, nothing is returned in the console. However, it does stop a location.reload() line from executing. There isn't really a "problem" that I can really define. The script works, but something is causing the script to become too large, which I'm assuming is because the PHP script is stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Why are you preparing the statement and binding the variables on each execution of the loop? This is a classic case of failing to understand the real purpose of prepared statements: prepare them *once* and execute them many times.

Comment: Well, lines like `$h<=$hashtags` don't make sense, since you can't really compare integers and arrays.  More importantly, arrays are zero indexed, meaning that `$arr[$i]` returns null and raises a warning when `$i == count($arr)`.  Furthermore, you probably don't want to be iterating by hand ANYWAY, and should look in to [foreach loops](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).  Other things you may want to look into: [upsert](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).  Also, [preg_match_all doesn't work that way](http://us3.php.net/preg_match_all)

Comment: Thank you `FrankieTheKneeMan` and `Mike W` for your help. In the past I've never had to use arrays, regex, loops, etc, so this was a learning experience. Working with regex itself was what led to the unusually sloppy code, so I'll take what I can and hopefully be able to work with all of this a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (preg_match_all("/(?<=@)[\w-]+/i", $post, $matches)) {
    foreach($matches[0] as $mVal) {
        $uMSQL = "INSERT INTO `messages` (`to`, `from`, `message`, `sent`) VALUES (:to, :from, '<p>tagged you in a post</p>', NOW())";
        $uMQ = $con->prepare($uMSQL);
        $uMQ->bindParam(':from', $author, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $uMQ->bindParam(':to', $mVal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $uMQ->execute();
    }
}
if (preg_match_all("/#+[\w-]+/", $post, $hashtags)) {
    foreach($hashtags[0] as $htVal) {
        //Assuming that the `hashtag` column is a unique key on this table
        //WHICH IT SHOULD BE...
        $htMSQL = "INSERT INTO `hashtags` (`hashtag`) VALUES (:hashtag) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET `used` = `used` + 1";
        $htMQ = $con->prepare($htMSQL);
        $htMQ->bindParam(':hashtag', $htVal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $htMQ->execute();
    }
}
```

That should get you closer, anyway.  I might recommend doing fewer calls to the database (for instance, in this case, you can get away with just two, no matter how large the post is), for transactional safety and a little bit of a speed boost.